# pickle.load is not working

Tags: python, pickle

This is a test program for my big program. It says I get a EOerror.

```
import pickle
list = ["11", "22"]
outFile = open("save.txt", "wb")
pickle.dump(list, outFile)
outFile.close
inFile = open("save.txt", "rb")
inFile = pickle.load(inFile)
print(inFile)
yea = inFile[1]
print(yea)
input("")
```

It gives me an error on line 7.

Comment: OMG I had to count lines.  Just post the traceback next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
outFile.close
```

You didn't call the method!

In the future, note that the preferred way of opening files is

```
with open(name, mode) as f:
    do_whatever(f)
```

This handles closing the file at the end of the `with` block, no matter how control leaves it.